# Performace API - not supported in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, performance, api, safari

I am planning to track page load time in Javascript with the help of Performance Navigation API. But , It is not supported in safari.
Here is the code:

```
*var performance = window.performance;
var timet = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].duration;*
```

Receiving an error "Performance" is undefined. It seems Performace API is deprecated.
Is there any alternate way to capture page load time using Javascript?

Comment: The problem is that `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")` returns an empty array in Safari (still the case as of Safari 14...)
Relevant bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184363

Comment: Shame on Safari. Seems they should get rid of it and only use Chrome even on Apple devices...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")` returns an empty array in Safari (still the case as of Safari 14...)

Relevant bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184363

Note that you can use the old version of the API exposed as `performance.timing`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing
It doesn't have all the same data and some data might have different format though.

Comment: Could not catch the error with `if ( performance.getEntriesByType("navigation") ) { ... }`, so I used `if ( typeof (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")) === 'object' ) { ... }`